# ajaxComplete function runs in infinity mode

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my web app made with JQueryMobile i insert the content of an .xml File. Due to ajax the .xml file only gets loaded if the page gets an refresh. So i tried to execute the function via ajaxComplete. Unfortunately the function is executed every milliseconds. But i would like the function only start one time. Any ideas what i made wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$( document ).ajaxComplete( function()
{
$.get("folder/job", function(XMLjobArray){
$(XMLjobArray).find("job").each(function(){
var $myJob = $(this);
var title = $myJob.attr("title");
var url = $myJob.attr("url");
$("#a").append('<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-last-child ui-btn-up-d"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a rel="external" target="_blank" data-ajax="false" href="'+url+'" class="ui-link-inherit">'+title+'</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>'); })
});
});
```

For a better view have a look here: http://pastebin.com/Aa3b2s9W

Comment: placing a ajax call inside `ajaxComplete` is very bad. you have created the infinite loop.

Comment: @anto-j-subash ok. i understand. But how can i run the script/function without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery.get()` (or `$.get()` ) method loads data from the server using a HTTP GET request. (see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ ). 
Therefore, in this case, whenever you load the file, you then ask jQuery to get the file again.

I'm not sure how you really want to be loading your .xml file, but the call to $.get() should be done in an other context. For instance, you could do something like :

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.get("folder/job.xml", function(data){
        /* Do whatever you want with your data */
    });
});
```

You can also use the "load" event ( `$(document).ready(...)` ). In both case, whenever your page gets loaded it will fetch your XML file and process it. This will append only when your page gets loaded.

Comment: But it is not working because the page (file.html) is loaded via ajax. No page load -> no Script start

Comment: So, in a "parent.html" page, you are loading a "children.html" page, which contains a script that execute an ajax call to get a "file.xml" and process it. But the "load" event is never launched for the "children.html" page ?

Comment: Correct. Everything inside the function() does not load. If i add the $( document ).ajaxComplete( the script does load but in infinity loop.

Comment: Does going directly for $.get("folder/job.xml", function(data){}); (not in the $(document).load() function) would do the job ? I also assume that you don't have control on how your "children.html" page will be loaded ?

Comment: IMOO, it's absolutely normal that the $(document).load() doesn't work. As the load() event is never called in a page loaded via Ajax. But using $.get() outside of a event listener should work.
If you really need to wait for something before you do your second Ajax call (the one started by the "children.html" file), there might be other events to listen to (such as 'domready' maybe ?).
Otherwise you still may want to do it with $(document).ajaxComplete() and unbind the listener after the first call is complete.

Comment: And furthermore, the $(document).ajaxComplete() may not be called when you want. I would definitely go for a direct :

<script type="text/javascript" >$.get("folder/job.xml",function(data){});</script>

But unfortunately I haven't had a chance to do any further tests yet.